# JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input in field name

Tags: json, objectmapper

Hi I have the following json that I need to convert to a class.

```
{
  "codiceABI": "",
  "tipoCliente": "",
  "tipoEsecutore": "",
  "cliente": {
    "codiceFiscale": "",
    "partitaIVA": "",
    "ndg": "",
    "tipologiaGiuridica": "",
    "cognomeRagioneSociale": "",
    "nome": "",
    "sesso": "",
    "luogoNascitaCostituzione": "",
    "provinciaNascitaCostituzione": "",
    "paeseNascitaCostituzione": "",
    "dataNascitaCostituzione": "",
    "residenza": {
      "comune": "",
      "indirizzo": "",
      "provincia": "",
      "cap": "",
      "paese": ""
    },
    "domicilio": {
    "comune": "",
    "indirizzo": "",
    "provincia": "",
    "cap": "",
    "paese": ""
  },
  "pep": "NO",
  "tipologiaAttivitaEconomica": "",
  "settoreAttivitaEconomica": "",
  "codiceRamoATECO": "",
  "tipoAttivitaEconomica": "",
  "provinciaAttivita": "",
  "paeseAttivita": "",
  "cittadinanzaPF": [
    "",
    ""
  ],
  "paeseCasaMadrePG": "",
  "specieGiuridicaPG": "",
  "notePensionatoNonOccupato": "",
  "paeseRelazione": [
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ]
},
"esecutore": {
  "tipologiaAttivitaEconomica": "",
  "settoreAttivitaEconomica": "",
  "codiceRamoATECO": "",
  "tipoAttivitaEconomica": "",
  "provinciaAttivita": "",
  "paeseAttivita": "",
  "notePensionatoNonOccupato": "",
  "specieGiuridicaPG": "",
  "paeseRelazione": [
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ],
  "cognome": "",
  "nome": "",
  "sesso": "",
  "codiceFiscale": "",
  "ndg": "",
  "luogoNascita": "",
  "provinciaNascita": "",
  "paeseNascita": "",
  "dataNascita": "",
  "residenza": {
    "comune": "",
    "indirizzo": "",
    "provincia": "",
    "cap": "",
    "paese": ""
  },
  "domicilio": {
    "comune": "",
    "indirizzo": "",
    "provincia": "",
    "cap": "",
    "paese": ""
  },
  "pep": "",
  "cittadinanzaPF": [
    "086",
    ""
  ],
  "documento": {
    "tipo": "",
    "numero": "",
    "autoritaRilascio": "",
    "dataRilascio": ""
  }
},
"presenzaTitolareEffettivo": "",
"documentoClienteEsecutoreDelegato": {
  "tipo": "",
  "numero": "",
  "autoritaRilascio": "",
  "dataRilascio": ""
},
"rapportiOperazioni": [
  {
    "scopoOperazione": "",
    "tipoRapporto": "",
    "operazioneOccasionale": "",
    "contanteReale": "",
    "importoOperazione": 0,
    "paeseControparte": "",
    "provinciaControparte": "",
    "numeroRapporto": "",
    "note": "Darlehen",
    "noteProvenienzaDenaro": "",
    "naturaOperazione": "",
    "divisa": "",
    "banconote200": 0,
    "banconote500": 0,
    "dichiarazioneTransfrontaliera": "",
    "provenienzaDenaro": "",
    "abiprovenienza": ""
  }  
],
"titolariEffettivi": [
  {
    "cognome": "",
    "nome": "",
    "sesso": "",
    "codiceFiscale": "",
    "ndg": "",
    "luogoNascita": "",
    "provinciaNascita": "",
    "paeseNascita": "",
    "dataNascita": "",
    "residenza": {
      "comune": "",
      "indirizzo": "",
      "provincia": "",
      "cap": "",
      "paese": ""
    },
    "domicilio": {
      "comune": "",
      "indirizzo": "",
      "provincia": "",
      "cap": "",
      "paese": ""
    },
    "pep": "NO",
    "cittadinanzaPF": [
      "086",
      ""
    ],
    "documento": {
      "tipo": "",
      "numero": "",
      "autoritaRilascio": "",
      "dataRilascio": ""
    }
  }
],
"autore": "",
"dataAggiornamento": "",
"filiale": "",
"flagCommit": "",
"dataVersioneKyc": "",
"indicatoriX": [
  ""
],
"indicatori9": [
  0
],
"poteriRappresentanzaEsecutore": "",
"comportamentoClienteEsecutore": ""
}
```

and the respective class is

```
 public class ShAmlRiskKycInput implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public ShAmlRiskKycInput() {
  }

  private String codiceABI;
  private String tipoCliente;
  private String tipoEsecutore;
  private ShAmlRiskKycInputCliente cliente;
  private ShAmlRiskKycInputEsecutore esecutore;
  private String presenzaTitolareEffettivo;
  private ShAmlRiskKycInputDocumento documentoClienteEsecutoreDelegato;
  private ShAmlRiskKycInputRapportoOperazione[] rapportiOperazioni;
  private ShAmlRiskKycInputTitolareEffettivo[] titolariEffettivi;
  private String autore;
  private Date dataAggiornamento;
  private String filiale;
  private String flagCommit;
  private Date dataVersioneKyc;
  private String[] indicatoriX;
  private int[] indicatori9;
  private String poteriRappresentanzaEsecutore;
  private String comportamentoClienteEsecutore;
}
```

and

```
public class ShAmlRiskKycInputCliente implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public ShAmlRiskKycInputCliente() {
  }

  private String codiceFiscale;
  private String partitaIVA;
  private String ndg;
  private String tipologiaGiuridica;
  private String cognomeRagioneSociale;
  private String nome;
  private String sesso;
  private String luogoNascitaCostituzione;
  private String provinciaNascitaCostituzione;
  private String paeseNascitaCostituzione;
  private Date dataNascitaCostituzione;
  private ShAmlRiskKycInputIndirizzo residenza;
  private ShAmlRiskKycInputIndirizzo domicilio;
  private String pep;
  private String tipologiaAttivitaEconomica;
  private String settoreAttivitaEconomica;
  private String codiceRamoATECO;
  private String tipoAttivitaEconomica;
  private String provinciaAttivita;
  private String paeseAttivita;
  private String[] cittadinanzaPF;
  private String paeseCasaMadrePG;
  private String specieGiuridicaPG;
  private String notePensionatoNonOccupato;
  private String[] paeseRelazione;
}
```

as it looks like the error is inside this second class..

The error is following:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected end-of-input 
in field name
at [Source: (String)"{
  "codiceABI": "",
  "tipoCliente": "",
  "tipoEsecutore": "",
  "cliente": {
    "codiceFiscale": "",
    "partitaIVA": "",
    "ndg": "",
    "tipologiaGiuridica": "",
    "cognomeRagioneSociale": ".",
    "nome": "",
    "sesso": "",
    "luogoNascitaCostituzione": "",
    "provinciaNascitaCostituzione": "",
    "paeseNascitaCostituzione": "",
    "dataNascitaCostituzione": "",
    "residenza": {
    "[truncated 637 chars]; line: 44, column: 1161]
    at [Source: (String)"{
    "codiceABI": "",
    "tipoCliente": "",
    "tipoEsecutore": "",
    "cliente": {
      "codiceFiscale": "",
      "partitaIVA": "",
      "ndg": "",
      "tipologiaGiuridica": "",
      "cognomeRagioneSociale": "",
      "nome": "",
      "sesso": "",
      "luogoNascitaCostituzione": "",
      "provinciaNascitaCostituzione": "",
      "paeseNascitaCostituzione": "",
      "dataNascitaCostituzione": "",
      "residenza": {
       "[truncated 637 chars]; line: 43, column: 26] (through reference chain: it.raiffeisen.m3.dao.sadas.v1_0.ShAmlRiskKycInput["cliente"])
```

Here the code where I make the conversion

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
 ShAmlRiskKycInput input = mapper.readValue(inputjsonISO, ShAmlRiskKycInput.class);
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you try to parse the JSON string? Is it happening in request handler?

Comment: yes sorry I added that part, and no its not in the request handler

Comment: Which is the version of `jackson-databind` that you are using?

Comment: the version of jackson-databind is 2.9.9

Comment: How this `inputjsonISO` is populated? Do you have all the corresponding POJO classes for all the objects inside the input JSON? All those classes have getters and setters?

Comment: yes the inputjsonISO is the json that i posted in the question. And all the classes have getters and setters

Comment: I've tried with the same JSON declared as string and there where no issues in parsing it. I want to know how you are getting this `inputjsonISO`. Is it loaded from file? or its received as a response of an API call?.. Issue seems to be with the incomplete JSON string for the mapper

Comment: byte[] inputbyteISO = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(json);
String inputjsonISO = new String(inputbyteISO, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
   
String inputjsonUTF8 = new String(inputjsonISO.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

Comment: I am receiving it as base64 in iso format from a webcics component

Comment: i thought of using @JsonIgnore because in fact I only need two strings from this class..

Comment: it didn't work..